# How to update $PATH

Tags: python, scripting, path, bash

I am writing a python/pygtk application that is adding some custom scripts (bash) in a certain folder in $HOME (eg. `~/.custom_scripts`).

I want to make that folder available in `$PATH`. So every time the python app is adding the script, that script could be instantly available when the user is opening a terminal (eg. gnome-terminal).

Where do you suggest to "inject" that $PATH dependecy ? `.bashrc`, `/etc/profile.d`, etc. ?
What advantages / disadvantages I might encounter ?

For example if i add a script to export the new path in /etc/profile.d, the path is not being updated until I re-login.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~/.bashrc is read every time gnome-terminal is opened, (assuming the user has SHELL set to /bin/bash).

Be sure to check os.environ['PATH'] to see if the directory has already been added, so that the script doesn't add it more than once.

Answer (score 2):

`.profile` would be a reasonable place if it's a per-user install; `/etc/profile.d` for system-wide installs.  (You'll need root to do that, of course.)

Your installer won't be able to change the path of the current shell (unless it's being run via `source`, which would be...odd.)

Answer (score 2):

For scripts that go in the $HOME directory you'd typically use $HOME/bin folder instead which is (usually) on the path.

Answer (score 1):

/etc/profile.d would add it to every user's path

~/.bashrc would just be your own

you can always do "$ source ~/.bashrc" to re-read the config files.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I misread the original question, so this snippet is only useful for modifying `PATH`, but not for persisting it...

This can all be done using the `os` module:

```
import os
USER_HOME = os.path.expanduser('~')
os.environ['PATH'] += ":" + os.path.join(USER_HOME, '.custom_scripts')
```

This appends `:~/.custom_scripts` to the end of the `$PATH`, since `PATH` must always be colon-delimited.

Comment: ...for as long as your Python script is running, which is fairly useless.

Comment: Hah, reading comprehension error on my part. I've updated my answer to reflect the limited scope of usefulness. *shame*

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't. It's the user choice whether he wants that in the `PATH`, in what cases and how to achieve that. What you can do is inform the user about the directory where your scripts reside and suggest putting it to the `PATH`.

Or maybe you're asking from the user's perspective?

Comment: Well thats what the application is doing, managing "custom" scripts ... When installing this application the user already expects that.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you establish the appropriate `PATH` upon the first call to your module (i.e. in your module's `__init__.py`):

```
# this is your module's __init__.py
import sys
eggs = ['/path/to/egg/1.egg', '/path/to/egg/2.egg']
for egg in eggs:
    sys.path.append(egg)
```

Comment: `sys.path` is not `$PATH`; the former is where the Python interpreter searches for modules, the latter is where the OS searches for executable files.